# Image files and relative paths in scala

Tags: file, scala, file-io, scala-swing

I am trying to access some images for from image panel using a relative path.  In the Eclipse project I have a folder named images with on image inside.  Here is my code:

```
  val top = new MainFrame {

    title = "Predator and Prey Agent simulation"

    val buttonExit = new Button {
      text = "Exit"
      action = Action("Exit") {
        WorldActor.run(false)
        closer
      }
    }

    val buttonStart = new Button {
      text = "Start"
      action = Action("Start") {
        switchPanes()
      }
    }

    val s = new Dimension(500, 700)

    contents = new ImagePanel(0, 1) {
      for (i <- 0 until 5){
        contents+= new Label("")
      }
      contents += buttonStart
      contents += buttonExit
      contents+= new Label("")

      minimumSize = s
      maximumSize = s
      preferredSize = s
      imagePath = ("\\PredatorPrey\\images\\gnp-canadian-lynx-kitten.jpg")

      }
    }
```

Every time the above code runs I get a javax.imageio.IIOException.  Here is the imapePanel class:

```
case class ImagePanel(rows0: Int, cols0: Int) extends GridPanel(rows0, cols0) {
  private var _imagePath = ""
  private var bufferedImage: BufferedImage = null

  def imagePath = _imagePath

  def imagePath_=(value: String) {
    _imagePath = value
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(_imagePath))
  }

  override def paintComponent(g: Graphics2D) = {
    if (null != bufferedImage) g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null)
    }
  }
```

Does anyone know how to fix that path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i just use awt:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit
val image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.createImage("images/kitten.jpg")
```

EDIT:

Also, remove `\\PredatorPrey\\` from the image path.

EDIT 2:
Just explaining what was wrong with the code as cited in the question - when a file path name starts with "/" (or "\" in windows), it becomes absolute ( slash represents the root of the current file system/ drive). Also, the code included the project name in the path. Since the application is run from *inside* the project, the project directory is not needed in the path (you are already inside that directory!).

Comment: Your post helped me the most in fixing the problem, but not exactly because of what you answered.  I remembered just after I saw in you post.  I needed to remove the project name PredatorPrey AND the initial / from the path declaration.  Maybe you can edit your post to say that and I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use a relative path then you need to drop the beginning slash in your path.

```
imagePath = ("PredatorPrey\\images\\gnp-canadian-lynx-kitten.jpg")
```

Comment: I tried that exact same thing.  When I used the relative path I get an javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file! ecxeption.  BUt everything works fine when I use the absolute path.